# How I can export functionally variable

Tags: javascript

I want to export variable 
Code looks like:

```
let url = '';
module.exports = Object.freeze({
  url: url
});
```

I would to have possibility to edit property that it can be accesses by dot.

```
ObjectWhichHasAboveCode.url = "http://help.me"
```

Can I achieve it in any functional way? Override assign operator?

I tried;

```
1) url: () => url
2) url: {
    value: url,
    writable: true
   }
```

Is it possible to achieve it somehow?

Second question:

Can I mix exporting Object.freeze methods together with let variable?

[EDIT] Syntax error

Comment: Why are you freezing the object if you wish it to be mutable? By the way your object literal has syntax errors.

Comment: @plalx I don't see any syntax error in the object initializer.

Comment: For every assign I want to have new variable. I just ask it is possible. I don't want to use global variables in fact. I want to be as close to functional language as I can. But unfortunately  code which my code depends on require access to such signle property. They are accessing it just by dot.

Comment: @Oriol My bad, I was not aware of this succinct syntax ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are looking for is the module pattern. You want method implementations to be frozen on the object, but you do not want the state of the object to be entirely immutable.

Here's what could be done:

```
module.exports = (function () {
  var url;

  return Object.freeze({
    get url() { return url; },
    setUrl: function (value) { url = value; }  
  });

})();
```

The url would have to be set using `theObject.setUrl('some url')`, but all the other members would be immutable. The `url` could still be accessed using the dot notation (`theObject.url`).

EDIT:

Actually, what you are looking for is `Object.seal`.

```
module.exports = (function () {
  var url;

  return Object.seal({
    get url() { return url; },
    set url(value) { url = value; }
  });

})();
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is almost what I want. BUT here you need to use setUrl to set this parameter. This is how I'm setting everything in my project but as I mentioned. There is code which use my piece of code. They set url parameter via "=" operator.

Comment: This sounds in fact weird... I just need to give up and just create editable property :D

Comment: @Myrthan You may define all members using `Object.defineProperties` and configure them as non-writable and non-configurable. That would allow you to use the dot notation while preserving the immutability of existing accessors/methods. However, new members could be added on the object since the object will not completely be frozen.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I implemented exactly as you commented by defineProperties.

Answer (score 0):

Seal the object instead of freezing it:

> The `Object.seal()` method seals an object, preventing new properties
>   from being added to it and marking all existing properties as
>   non-configurable. Values of present properties can still be changed as
>   long as they are writable.

```
module.exports = Object.seal({url});
```